# Apache not running on my machine on OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, apache, open-source

After doing `tail -20 /var/log/apache2/error_log`:

```
[Fri Sep 13 03:14:30 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/Documents/
[Fri Sep 13 03:17:00 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/Documents/
[Fri Sep 13 03:17:03 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/Documents/
[Fri Sep 13 03:17:32 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/Documents/hello.html
[Fri Sep 13 03:25:08 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Flipkart-MacBookPro-344.local for ServerName
[Fri Sep 13 03:25:08 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Sep 13 03:25:08 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Sep 13 03:25:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 13 03:33:14 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
httpd : Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Flipkart-MacBookPro-344.local for ServerName
[Fri Sep 13 03:33:14 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Sep 13 03:33:14 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Sep 13 03:33:14 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 13 04:15:14 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/anushil.sharma/Sources/website/code/www/hello.html
[Fri Sep 13 04:24:00 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

What's wrong with this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: its seems apache dont have proper permissions on the Document directory.

Comment: So i should do chown to www-data on the Document root.

Comment: yes you should change the ownership to www-data and also chmod to 755 to the Document root.

Comment: How was apace installed?